# Open a local mbtiles map in Mobile atlas creator "Mobac"

Tags: mobile-atlas-creator

I'm trying to add **local mbtile into mobac**.

I have tried to create an XML file in the map sources folder with this information

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localTileSQLite>
   <name>Custom SQLite atlas</name>
   <sourceFile>D:\myplace\newmap.mbtiles</sourceFile>
   <atlasType>MBTiles</atlasType>
   <backgroundColor>#000000</backgroundColor>
   <tileImageType>PNG</tileImageType> <!-- optional -->
</localTileSQLite>
```

but I can't find anything new when I try to add the map inside Mobac.

Answer (score 0):

Have you positioned MOBAC over the area covered by the MBTiles file?

Open Open Street Map Public Transport and right drag/zoom to where you want to be. Then switch to the MBTiles.

Comment: Yes I'm over the area that the MBTiles should cover.

But I can't switch between Open Street Map and the MBTiles, because Mobac haven't recognized the xml file, so I can't add it into a mapsource.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to change the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```